# Return total count of enteries using raw sql in Vapor

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

I'm trying to route an incoming `GET` to return the following string:

"The total number of our models is 12"

where 12 is the actual number of entries of a specific model saved to the database.

Now one way to do this is to use the following:

```
func index(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<String> {
  return Model.query(on: req).all().map { models in
    return "The total number of our models is \(models.count)"
  }
}
```

This is the most documented and at the same time most inefficient way of doing this. I couldn't find any query that maps to `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Model;"`

So I resorted to writing my own raw SQL against the database. I've gotten this far but I can't figure out how to map `[PostgreSQLColumn : PostgreSQLData]` to `Future<String>`

```
  func index(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<String> {
    return req.withPooledConnection(to: .psql) { (conn) in
      conn.raw("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MODEL").all()
          ///....something something 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of just `all()` and `first()` you could  use `all(decoding:)` and `first(decoding:)` to decode returned raw rows

```swift
struct CountResult: Content {
    let count: Int64
}

func index(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<String> {
    req.withPooledConnection(to: .psql) { conn in
        conn.raw("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM MODEL").first(decoding: CountResult.self).map {
            $0?.count ?? 0
        }.map {
            "The total number of our models is \($0)"
        }
    }
}
```

Also I'd suggest to take a look at [SwifQL](https://github.com/SwifQL/SwifQL) and [Bridges](https://github.com/SwifQL/Bridges) libraries to work with raw SQL in type-safe way.

#### With pure SwifQL

```swift
struct CountResult: Content {
    let count: Int64
}

func index(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<String> {
    req.withPooledConnection(to: .psql) { conn in
        let query = SwifQL
            .select(Fn.count(MyTable.table.*))
            .from(MyTable.table)
        return conn.raw(query)
            .first(decoding: CountResult.self)
            .map { $0?.count ?? 0 }
            .map {
                "The total number of our models is \($0)"
            }
    }
}
```

#### With SwifQL + Bridges

```swift
func index(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<String> {
    MyTable.query(on: .psql, on: req).count().map {
        "The total number of our models is \($0)"
    }
}
```

Comment: You could text me in Discord to @iMike#3049 I'd love to help with SwifQL

Comment: This is great! thank you so much for such a thorough answer! Could you expand on the answer to return a `Future<String>` so it's a direct answer to the question? I think changing the map block to ` return `"The total number of our models is \($0?.count ?? 0)"` should do it.

Comment: `map` or `transform(to: "")` can do it. Please check updated answer

Answer (score 4):

To return the count of rows you can do:

```swift
Model.query(on: req).count()
```

You can also apply filters to that query as well